# How to know in .bashrc who is initiator?

Tags: ruby, bash

I am starting new bash from my ruby script like below

```
exec("#{ENV['SHELL']} -l")
```

I want to do and avoid some action in .bashrc if the bash is started from above ruby script.

Is there any way I can identify in .bashrc that my .bashrc was executed from a ruby script?

Comment: Why would you want to run .bashrc from a ruby script?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would just set some enviromental variable in your ruby script and in .bashrc test for that

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying this out already. I was thinking is there some better way to do this.